# Performing a vlookup with a dynamic lookup_value

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, offset

[image]I would like to perform a vlookup with a dynamic lookup_value. The reason for this is that the actual lookup_value row will be different everytime I apply run my VBA code. Since the Vlookup formula will shift up or down every time ideally, I wuold like to use OFFSET in my VLOOKUP to reference whatever the new row it is on.

Here you can see the vlookup is referencing a cell in a column that is -5 columns away. The table_array is on sheet2:

ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(OFFSET(activecell,0,-5),'BB Lookup'!S:W,5,FALSE)"

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Seems like you have the gist of it down. Unclear what you want to change here. Do you just want to replace `activecell.offset(0, -5)` with the last row cell? If so, what column? Maybe add a photo if unable to explain clearly

Comment: Sure in this screenshot I changed the formula around a bit. For more background I have code before this that finds the first #N/A in Column E and then it applies the Vlookup.

Comment: I would like to find A4 in an array in a the sheet 'BB Lookup'. Everything works fine except for I can't get the lookup_value to reference the activecell.